Estimating correlation parameter from known value of bivariate normal distribution
I want to estimate the correlation parameter $\rho$ using the following expression taken from this paper (equation 10 on page 17):
$$ \hat{s}^2+\hat{\mu}^2=N_2(N^{-1}(\hat{\mu}),N^{-1}(\hat{\mu}), \rho) $$
where $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{s}^2$ are the sample mean and variance respectively which are known. $N^{-1}$ is the inverse of the univariate normal distribution and $N_2$ is the bivariate normal distribution.
My first thought is to solve numerically but is there any literature\previous work\experience on the best way to approach these expressions?
